# What are the real benefits of using STL?

Tags: c++, stl

How many of you use STL stuff extensively in your project?

I have never used STL stuff, for one, I am not a professional coder, just someone who wrote some programs/libraries for high performance computing applications if needed, and to me, I think STL is not particularly useful:

1, It offer some features like sort, hash-table, binary tree, but the implentations are usually not very optimzed and not good in terms of performance, I can easily find replacement or write by myself, with better performance, sometimes, far better.

2, It offer some containers that I can easily write by myself.

3, It uses significant amount of C++ structures/warppers/grammars, its really cost time for me to learn and master that.

So can I say STL is only for high-productivity programming when there are alot of programmers invovled in the project that they need a consistent programming interface stuff and I should not bother with it for my applications?

Comment: People tend to use the C++ standard library these days. If that is what you mean by STL, you may want to clarify the question.

Comment: 3 is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Your kicking a hornets nest by asking questions like that around here... but for my 2 cents I think you should consider the amount of time saved when applying STL code to parts of your application that really don't need optimisation

Comment: "I can easily find replacement or write by myself, with better performance, sometimes, far better" - perhaps you can find a replacement, but that's not a reason not to use the standard library. After all, you could find replacements for the replacements, so why use the replacements? And perhaps you could write your own, optimized for your use case, but you'd waste time and write bugs you could have avoided with a heavily-scrutinized library implementation.

Comment: I almost never write C++ without the standard library. Sure its not perfect on the efficiency front, but its usually close enough that the improved programmer efficiency is far more important. Avoiding bugs cannot be over valued. Safe, well documented, bug-free code is your friend.

Comment: If you can write better performing algorithms and data structures, why don't you contribute them to a project like libc++? That way the rest of us can benefit from your brilliance.

Comment: When programming in C do you also write your own strlen, strcat, strstr and so on? Those are "easy to write" on one's own as learning exercises but it doesn't mean one should do so in production code

Answer (score 8):

Just because you've taken a data structures and algorithms course in college doesn't mean you should actually be implementing these things. Without domain-specific knowledge, you're very likely wrong, and cannot implement a more efficient version of these data structures. They are general purpose algorithms and containers to make your life easy. They make your life easy by being:

1) Correct - you don't need to debug them.

2) Fast - they are just about as fast as can be for the general case.

3) Maintainable - both you and your peers can read and understand what they're doing. In many cases, uses of the standard library are self-documenting. Why reinvent the wheel?

I've taught data structures and algorithms, and I can tell you, the students who get the highest grades, write the fastest solutions, finish early, and write cleaner code, all make great use of the STL. The students who do the worst, spend their time reinventing the wheel, are pushing the deadline, have poor runtime and memory performance, are typically writing C-style code and/or writing code when they should be calling standard algorithms.

Even though you can often make domain-specific specializations to your base data structures, it's almost never worth it. The loss in readability is not worth the performance gain, and quite frankly, I've seen too many students looking to buy performance this way when they really have a conceptual gap somewhere else that has caused them to write slow code.

As someone who has been in industry: redefine what good code means. Maintainability is often a much more important factor than performance. As long as you're in the right ballpark on performance (big-Oh), it's usually not worth your time to micro-optimize unless you profile and demonstrate the need.